# How do the occupants survive a ship coming out of hyperdrive?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

According to [this post the Millennium Falcon travels approximately 20,000 light years per hour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/155327/39144).

Even assuming that regular ships travel at a greatly reduced speed compared to the Millennium Falcon: how can the human body (Jedi/Sith or otherwise), along with any items not strapped down withstand the deceleration of the ship without flying through the front of the ship or being dashed against the ship's walls?

Comment: All ships delpoy their glibblemanricular tlip diverters before coming out of hyperdrive to prevent this incident.

Comment: Related: [How do Star Wars hyperdrives work?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5658/68872)

Comment: They never travelled faster, space just got smaller. YMMV.

Comment: The same way they survived the jump in the first place.

Comment: I love how this question is addressed in Spaceballs: "We can't stop! We have to slow down first!"

Comment: The engines don't move the ship at all. The ship stays where it is and the engines move the universe around it.

Comment: @Tim - That sounds like pure, weapons grade balonium

Comment: @Valorum Impossible! Professor Farnworth's clone said it, so it must be true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is addressed in (amongst others) the [Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Incredible Cross Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_Incredible_Cross-Sections). Once a ship exits hyperspace, the crew experience a considerable de-acceleration. The ship's "[Acceleration Compensators](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Acceleration_compensator)" deal with this.

You might wish to note that hyperspace is described as being a *"different dimension" (one where the speed of light is presumably much higher) so the acceleration/de-acceleration spike is rather lower than you might think.

[image]

Comment: Timothy Zahn, in his Star Wars novels, typically uses the phrase "with a flicker of pseudomotion" to describe a ship's transition between normal space and hyperspace, suggesting that the ship doesn't experience acceleration within its own frame of reference.  Do any new canon (non-Legends) sources use this phrase?

Comment: @Gaultheria - I can't see it in any of my canon books

Comment: @Gaultheria - You may wish to note that Han came out of hyperspace messily and he was only traveling at a few hundred mph

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm by no means an expert on this, I'm just going to refer you to [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115078) for the answer. Note the third picture in particular.

I think this is how most universes explain stuff like that, from what I recall. Most of the time they just say they compensate for rapid acceleration, and don't mention deceleration, but remember that deceleration is just negative acceleration, or acceleration backwards.

Although I'm always more of a fan of the MST3K explanation:

> If you're wondering how he eats and breathes
>   
> And other science facts,
>   
> Just repeat to yourself "It's just a show,
>   
> I should really just relax."

Comment: A good answer, you've also found the duplicate I was looking for! However we normally don't recommend giving answers that say "It's a show just relax" as that's what we're here to do, answer questions.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just wanted to throw it in as a comparison to the 'I think this is how most universes explain it' part for fun :P

Comment: mst3k explanation trumps all